# how to execute sql queries from a shell script

Tags: shell, postgresql-9.1

I am writing a shell script to run bunch of queries in postgres.

This is the script that I have written.

```
#!/bin/sh
host="172.16.7.102"
username="priyank"
dbname="truaxis"
x=1
echo "Connection done"
while [ $x -le 3 ]
do
        x=$(($x + 1 ))
        echo "Connection $x"
        psql -h $host $dbname $username << EOF
        select * from students where sid = $x;
        EOF
done
```

There are two issues with this script.

1. pgtest1.sh: 17: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "done")
2. how do I pass $x in the sql dynamically

I want to create new db connection per iteration.

I am new to both postgre and shell.

Thanks

Priyank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) pgtest1.sh: 17: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "done")

You need to have EOF in its own line alone (without space etc)

```
     psql -h $host $dbname $username << EOF
        select * from students where sid = $x;
EOF
```

> 2) how do I pass $x in the sql dynamically

```
$ sh scriptname.sh value_of_x
```

then in your script

```
x=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

`EOF` the way you've specified cannot be indented. You need to do the following (note the dash *prior to* the here-doc token:

```
while [ $x -le 3 ] ; do
    psql foo bar <<-EOQ
        select * from students where sid = $x;
    EOQ
done
```

As a side note, why not use a `for` loop instead of `while`?

```
for (( x=$1 ; x<=3 ; x++ )) ; do
    foo
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the same except for my case it's for mysql. I'm using zsh. I set up an alias so that the shell will not do any globbing  when I call the script so that I can do this:

```
$ sql select * from Table
```

instead of:

```
$ sql select '*' from Table
```

The alias is:

```
alias sql='noglob sql'
```

I also use `sed` to automagically add quoting where necessary so that I can do this:

```
$ sql select * from Client where first_name like John% and last_name = Wiley
```

instead of:

```
$ sql select '*' from Client where first_name like "'John%'" and last_name = "'Wiley'"
```

In cases where I don't want the shell script to automagically add the quoting I omit the spaces before and after the = operator like this:

```
$ sql select t1.col1,t2.col2 from Table1 t1 join Table t2 on t1.client_id=t2.client_id.
```

I'm pasting the script here in case you might profit from it. It is zsh, and mysql-specific. You'll have to modify it to suit the way you pass the sql commands to be run in psql. The `mpager` program used in the script is another shell script that calls vim and ask it to act like a pager suitable for browsing the tabular output:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

function usage() {
  echo -n "Usage: $0 [-h] [-t] [-d db] [-q] [-v] [-n] [p] [-q] [sql commands]
   -d db   Use specified database instead of the default one
   -t      Do not 'tabularize' (borders) the output
   -v      Be verbose
   -n      Dry-run - show what command to be executed
   -p      Pipe output to mpager
   -q      Surpress own output, only show output from mysql
   -h      Show this help message
"
}

password=${DB_PASS:-secret}
db=${DB:-default_db}
user=${DB_USER:-username}

USE_TABLE='--table'
while getopts d:tvnhpq o
do
  case "$o" in
    d)  db=$OPTARG ;;
    t)  USE_TABLE='' ;;
    v)  verbose=1 ;;
    n)  dry_run='echo' ;;
    p)  use_mpager=t ;;
    h)  usage; exit 0 ;;
    q)  quiet=1;;
    *)  usage;
        exit 1 ;;
  esac
done
shift `expr $OPTIND - 1`

case $2 in
    database|databases)
    db=
    ;;
esac
if [ -z "$quiet" -a -n "$db" ]; then
    echo 1>&2 "Database: $db"
fi

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
  mysql --table -u $user -p$password $db "$@"
  exit
fi

to_run=`echo $*|sed -e "s/ \(=\|like\) *\([^'][^ ]*\+\)/ \1 '\2'/g"`

# This helps for debugging. Show what is going to run when output is going to a
# terminal:
if [ -t 1 ]; then
    echo "to_run: $to_run" 1>&2
fi

if [ -n "$verbose" ]; then
    echo "mysql $USE_TABLE -u $user -p$password $db -e ${(q)to_run}"
fi
if [ -n "$use_mpager" ]; then
    $dry_run mysql $USE_TABLE -u $user -p$password $db -e "$to_run" | mpager
else
    $dry_run mysql $USE_TABLE -u $user -p$password $db -e "$to_run"
fi
```