# Query with UNION ALL won't write in html

Tags: html, postgresql

I have a query with UNION all statements which i want write in html file, but it's doing only columns and writing 0 0 in it.
How can i pass it?
My query:

```
/usr/bin/psql -h localhost -U etaxi_prod_due etaxi_prod_due --html -c "with summary as (select count(id) as \"Summary\" from archived_order 
where data like '%"pmi":2568%' 
and finished between current_date - interval '1 day' and current_date

UNION ALL

select count(id) as \"Summary\" from archived_order 
where data like '%"pmi":2569%' 
and finished between current_date - interval '1 day' and current_date

UNION ALL

select count(id) as \"Summary\" from archived_order 
where data like '%"pmi":2570%'
and finished between current_date - interval '1 day' and current_date

UNION ALL

select count(id) as \"Summary\" from archived_order
where data like '%"pmn":"CHILD_SEAT"%'
and finished between current_date - interval '1 day' and current_date
), app as 

(select count(id) as \"Etaximo\" from archived_order
where data like '%"pmn":"CHILD_SEAT"%'
and finished between current_date - interval '1 day' and current_date), oper as

(select count(id) as \"Operator\" from archived_order 
where data like '%"pmi":2568%' 
and finished between current_date - interval '1 day' and current_date

UNION ALL

select count(id) as \"Operator\" from archived_order 
where data like '%"pmi":2569%' 
and finished between current_date - interval '1 day' and current_date

UNION ALL

select count(id) as \"Operator\" from archived_order 
where data like '%"pmi":2570%'
and finished between current_date - interval '1 day' and current_date), sumcompl as 

(select count(id) as \"Summary Completed\" from archived_order 
where data like '%"pmi":2568%' and completed is true
and finished between current_date - interval '1 day' and current_date

UNION ALL

select count(id) as \"Summary Completed\" from archived_order 
where data like '%"pmi":2569%' and completed is true 
and finished between current_date - interval '1 day' and current_date

UNION ALL

select count(id) as \"Summary Completed\" from archived_order 
where data like '%"pmi":2570%' and completed is true
and finished between current_date - interval '1 day' and current_date

UNION ALL

select count(id) as \"Summary Completed\" from archived_order
where data like '%"pmn":"CHILD_SEAT"%' and completed is true
and finished between current_date - interval '1 day' and current_date
), result1 as (
select 
sum(\"Summary\") as \"Created\"
from summary
), result2 as 
(select 
sum(\"Summary Completed\") as \"Done\"
from sumcompl
), result3 as (select
sum(\"Operator\") as \"Operator\"
from oper
), result4 as (select
sum(\"Etaximo\") as \"Etaximo\"
from app 
)
select result1.\"Created\", result2.\"Done\", result3.\"Operator\", result4.\"Etaximo\" from result1, result2, result3, result4 order by result1.\"Created\", result2.\"Done\", result3.\"Operator\", result4.\"Etaximo\";">>/home/www/etaxi-prod-due/tmp/shara.html
```

I've tried to do some `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` but it won't help, i also tried to do something like encapsulation to make it looks like it without UNIONS at all for html. But it doesn't work also.

The output in html file from this query looks like this:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th align="center">Created</th>
    <th align="center">Completed</th>
    <th align="center">Operator</th>
    <th align="center">Etaximo</th>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>(1 row)<br />
</p>
```

But should be like this

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th align="center">Created</th>
    <th align="center">Completed</th>
    <th align="center">Operator</th>
    <th align="center">Etaximo</th>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="right">193</td>
    <td align="right">152</td>
    <td align="right">161</td>
    <td align="right">32</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>(1 row)<br />
</p>
```

Comment: What output does it give you if it's not html?  Can you update your post with current output?

Comment: @richyen if i'm running query in postgresql console without writing in file it's ok, but when i'm trying to run it outside of postgresql console with the commands `/usr/bin/psql` the html file does not contain values from the output, only zero's.

Comment: Seems like some of your double-quotes aren't escaped.  could that be the problem?

Comment: @richyen i've added the output in html. The table below is the exact output what i'm getting from query only in psql console.

Comment: @richyen It's me was playing, edited.

Comment: would it be acceptable to put your SQL in a file, then call `psql` with `-f` flag?

Comment: I don't think so. It's going to be executed from `sh` file with other queries with crontab but without `-f` flag.

Comment: I see.  If that's the case, can you try with a heredoc instead of `-c`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649794/how-to-execute-sql-queries-from-a-shell-script

Comment: @richyen I've tried to write only 1 query without any unions or something, and it's giving me the same `0` in html and `192` in `psql`

Comment: several of your `WHERE` clauses use double quotes that are not escaped (i.e., `'%"pmi":2568%' `)

Comment: @richyen Is it required to escape ALL of the double quotes? Because this example is json data.

Comment: @richyen I wasn't thinking about it AT ALL, it's working as it should be. THANK YOU. I was trying to get this done like all day

Comment: @richyen I did escapes to all of my double quotes and it worked correctly. Thank you very much. No one could tell me about this. I will know this thing now.